# How to draw an exploded pie chart in PHP with gdlib?

Tags: php, charts, gdlib

I can easily draw charts that look like this using `imagefilledarc`:

[Pie chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2K3z.png)

But how would I proceed if I wanted to add a little space in between the slices? Like this:

[Pie chart example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi7Gy.png)

How could I draw it like this? Basically, it would look as if center of the arc was moved by a specific angle and then it was cut off at the border of the original circle. How would I do that?

Comment: i would start using one of the php charting libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many option here

https://github.com/moklick/frontend-stuff